# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined onClick

Tags: reactjs, binding, typeerror, e-commerce, react-props

Tried multiple attempts to bind but still unable to use method addItem to add a product to cart,
App is my parent class, which im trying to pass the prop 'addItem'(Type: method) to Products, which will pass this method to Product(child of Products) and finally executed in Product

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    cartitems: [],
  }
  this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
}

addItem(item) {
  this.setState({
      cartitems : this.state.cartitems.concat([item]) });
...
 <Route exact path='/Products' component={Products} addItem={this.addItem} />
}
```

Products is a class that fetches data from my database and pass it down to Product like so

```
<div className="row">
    {items.map(item => <Product key={item.id} product={item} addItem={this.addItem} />)}
</div>
```

Finally, on Product i try to add the product to state cartitems whenever button is clicked,

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick= {() => this.props.addItem.bind(this, this.props.product) }>Add to Cart</button>
```

Am very new to React so would appreciate it tons if someone could help! The title is the error name. Thank you!!!

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to reproduce your issue, then I eventually could help you

Comment: App is my parent class, which im trying to pass the prop 'addItem'(Type: method) to Products, which will pass this method to Product(child of Products) and finally executed in Product. Hope this helps!

Comment: As I said, please provide minimal working example, e.g. on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing your Product component, but I believe you're missing a reference to props in one reference to your method.
I believe it should be

```
   {items.map(item => <Product key={item.id} product={item} addItem={this.props.
addItem} />)}
```

Comment: my product does not have much,its showing the mapped item(product)  from Productsprice, image URL and name, have changed as this suggested but is still not working...
TypeError: this.props.addItem is not a function